# Auto save email attachment from a specific mail id

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter

Daily we receive 7 email at 2 different timing. each mail is having one attachment. now I want to download email and save it to my local folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Save Outlook Attachments](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/OutlookAttachmentsSave) tool, you can automatically save attachments from incoming emails automatically thanks to [integration with Outlook rules](https://www.reliefjet.com/Essentials/Features/Integration#Rules). Just create an Outlook rule for your specific mail id and configure the tool to automatically run for this mail.

DISCLAIMER: I recommend this tool because I'm one of the developers, so feel free to ask any further questions.